# Extract content in paragraph Tags

Tags: c#, html, webclient

I have following html in string and i have to extract the content only in Paragraph tags  any ideas??

link is http://www.public-domain-content.com/books/Coming_Race/C1P1.shtml

I have tried

```
  const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<[^>]+.*?>";
    static string StripHTML(string inputString)
            {
                return Regex.Replace(inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
            }
```

it removes all html tags but i dont want to remove all the tags because this is the way how i can get content like paragraph by tags

secondly it makes line breaks to \n in text and and applying replace("\n","") dose not helps
one problem is that when i apply

```
int UrlStart = e.Result.IndexOf("<p>"), urlEnd = e.Result.IndexOf("<p>&nbsp;</p></td>\r" );
     string paragraph = e.Result.Substring(UrlStart, urlEnd);
     extractedContent.Text = paragraph.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

`<p>&nbsp;</p></td>\r` this appears at the end of paragraph but urlEnd dose not makes sure only paragraph is shown

the string extracted is shown in visual studio is like this
[image]
this page is downloaded by Webclient
End of HTMLpage

```
We will provide ourselves with ropes of\rsuitable length and strength- and- pardon me- you must not\rdrink more to-night.  our hands and feet must be steady and\rfirm tomorrow.\"\r<p>&nbsp;</p>     </td>\r    </tr>\r\r    <tr>\r     <td height=\"25\" width=\"10%\">\r     \r     </td><td height=\"25\" width=\"80%\" align=\"center\">\r       <font color=\"#FFFFFF\">\r       <font size=\"4\">1</font> &nbsp;\r       </font></td>\r     <td height=\"25\" width=\"10%\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"C2P1.shtml\">Next</a></td>\r    </tr>\r   </table>\r  </center>\r</div>\r<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"index.shtml\"><b>The Coming Race -by- Edward Bulwer Lytton</b></a></p>\r<P><B><center><A HREF=\"http://www.public-domain-content.com/encyclopedia.shtml\">Encyclopedia</a> - <A HREF=\"http://www.public-domain-content.com/books.shtml\">Books</a> - <A HREF=\"http://www.public-domain-content.com/religion.shtml\">Religion<a/> - <A HREF=\"http://www.public-domain-content.com/links2.shtml\">Links</a> - <A HREF=\"http://www.public-domain-content.com/\">Home</a> - <A HREF=\"http://www.webmaster-headquarters.com/mb/\">Message Boards</a></B><BR>This <a HREF=\"http://www.wikipedia.org/\">Wikipedia</a> content is licensed under the <a href=\"http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html\">GNU Fr
```

Comment: Oblig. Why using RegEx for parsing HTML is bad - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Oded Thanks, I was about to go dig up that URL myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (or something similar) instead.

A quick example, but you could do something like this:

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.Load("your_file_here.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode paragraph in document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//p"))
{
    // do something with the paragraph node here
    string content = paragraph.InnerText; // or something similar
}
```

Comment: anyway this dose not extract paragraph properly

Comment: @Afnan Sure, it was just a quick one-off example to demonstrate the simplicity of using a DOM-based solution, rather than one that uses a regular expression. You'll need to play around to figure out the right XPATH query to use with the `SelectNodes` function, and right properties of `HtmlNode` that you need to access.

Comment: I dont know what is wrong but this works for http://www.lipsum.com/ not the website i gave.i have analysed the content the website i have shown has its content witn alots of \ and \r

Comment: Please note in updated question having picture he \r is every where dose this causes problem